# Assembly parenthesis explanation

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, 32-bit

Hello im looking at an executable and don't have access to the source code. I haven't really come across this before and what I have found online, doesn't match the data that I am getting. Code:

```
0x08048d4c <+45>:   movsbl (%ebx,%eax,1),%esi
0x08048d50 <+49>:   and    $0xf,%esi
0x08048d53 <+52>:   add    (%ecx,%esi,4),%edx
```

My confusion is in the +52 line. "x/d $ecx" yields 2, and the value at %esi before the line is called, is 7. after that line is executed %edx is set to be equal to 3 (was zero before hand).

I thought that it would be 2 + (7*4), but that is not the case. Can someone please enlighten me. This is AT&T syntax i believe.

Comment: Also this is within a looping structure, i don't know if that would change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's at&t syntax and if you are confused by it, then switch gdb to intel syntax (`set disassembly-flavor intel`). You would see something like: `add edx, [ecx + esi*4]`
Anyway, this fetches an operand from memory, from address `ecx + esi*4`. You can see what that is using `x/d $ecx+$esi*4`. `x/d $ecx` doesn't help you anything because the addition is to the address, not the value.

Comment: I get it now, %ecx is actually pointing to the beginning of an array and that line just tells it how far down the array to go. Thank you.